# What is the proper way to add const?

Tags: c, constants

I'm looking for a rule on how to add aditional protection using const.

For example:

```
int** p1 = ...;
int** const p2=p1; // Legal
int* const * const p3=p1; // Legal
int* const * const p4=p3; // Legal
const int* const * const p5=p3; // Error

int*** cube1= &p1;
int* const ** cube2=cube1; // Error
and so on...
```

Comment: The "rule of how to add aditional protection" depends on what protection you are trying to achieve. Only you know what you need to protect and what to leave unprotected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to rules of const-correctness in pointer conversions, C language supports implicit conversion from type `T *` to type `const T *` for non-array data type `T`. That's the only "const-protecting" implicit conversion that C language supports.

In other words, conversion from `T *` to `const U *` is supported if `T` and `U` are *identical* non-array types. If `T` is somehow different from `U`, the implicit conversion is invalid (even if the difference between `T` and `U` are just some extra const-qualifiers).

To put it in simple terms, you are allowed to add `const` only after the most inner `*`. You are not allowed to add `const` at any deeper level of indirection. This is why your lines with `p5` and `cube` fail to compile.

```
int *p = 0;
const int *cp = p; // OK: `const` is added after the first `*`

int **pp = 0;
const int *const *cpp = pp; // Error: a "deep" `const` added
```

Sometimes in your code you might need to circumvent these restrictions and add some extra `const` at deeper levels of indirection. In that case you have no choice but to use an explicit cast

```
int **pp = 0;
const int *const *cpp = (const int *const *) pp;
```

P.S. C++ relaxed some of these limitations, creating a more logical system of const-correctness rules. Alas C never took any steps in that direction.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the quick answer! Question - Why `int* const ** cube2=cube1` not working even when I added const after the most inner`*` ?

Comment: @StavAlfi: By "most inner `*`" I mean the righmost `*`. In this case you added `const` after the second `*` from inside. That's not the most inner one.

Comment: What is "righmost `*`" ?

Comment: @StavAlfi I meant "rightmost". In this case - closest to the identifier being declared.

Answer (score 2):

`const` generally applies to the value defined on the left side of it.

Example:

```
int const *ptr = &val;
```

in the above code snippet, `const` belongs to `int` and not the `*ptr`.

if you move `*` behind `const`, it will make `ptr` constant pointer

```
int *const ptr = &val;
```

now `const` belongs to pointer and not the `int`

Now see another example

```
const int *ptr = &val;
```

Only when there's a `const` on the left most side of a statement, it then applies to whatever is on the right side of it, in the above code snippet, it is `int`.

Comment: Thanks for the information but I dont see how it answer my question. Sory If my question wasn't clear enough. I'm looking for some guide lines about how to find the currect place to put const.